# Difficult Ordinary Differential Equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering how to solve the following ODE:

Find $y(1)$ given $y(0)=1$ and

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2ye^{-5x^2}$

So far I got:

$\int \frac{1}{y} dy = 2 \int e^{-5x^2} dx$

On the left hand side I got $\ln|y|$ but did not know how to continue on the right hand integral. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say "On the left hand side I got ln|y| " because you know the function logarithm. If one doesn't know the function logarithm , he cannot. This is exactly the same for the right hand integral : if one knows the function Erf(x), he can continue. If he doesn't know the function Erf(x), he cannot. See : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales


An alternative way not requiring the knowledge of special functions is solving with infinite series.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int e^{-5x^2}\; dx = \frac{\sqrt{5\pi}}{10} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{5} x\right)$$
where $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).  It is not an elementary function.

Comment: Does this mean you cannot solve this question?

Comment: Well you also have boundary conditions which you impose as the limits of integration since all it asked for is what $y(1)$ is

Comment: You can solve the question, just not with elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

Following Robert Israel's guidance the solution has the form
$$y(x) = c_{0} \, \exp\left[\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}} \, \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{5} \, x)\right].$$
Since $y(0) = 1$ and $\operatorname{erf}(0) = 0$ then
$$y(x) = \exp\left[\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}} \, \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{5} \, x)\right].$$
Now,
$$y(1) = e^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}} \, \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{5})} = 4.066422474604290915236336...$$